# I don't want the camera to move when I click the marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm using the [google_map_flutter] package.

When I click the marker, I don't want the screen to move to the center of the marker.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Try set

```
consumeTapEvents=false
```

as argument of Marker constructor.

```
Marker marker =Marker(consumeTapEvents=false)
```

Comment: But it doesn't show infowindow then.

Comment: I can't get this to work. There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39868) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on your GoogleMap you can set a initialCameraPosition with some default target, like:

```
 initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      zoom: 13,
      target: LatLng(
        defaultLat,
        defaultLng,
      ),
    ),
```

Then you can get your map controller from the onMapCreated, like:

```
late GoogleMapController _mapController;

void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController googleMapsController) async {
  _mapController = googleMapsController;
  //rest of your code...
}
```

And use it on the onTap() method from the Marker to "lock" your camera position by keeping it with the default target. Like:

```
  Marker(
  markerId: const MarkerId('id'),
  onTap: () {
    _mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          zoom: 13,
          target: LatLng(
            defaultLat,
            defaultLng,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

It's not ideal since you still may notice the camera slightly trying to move, but it stays at the locked position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep show info on marker tap, then you can use GoogleMapController.showMarkerInfoWindow()

```
Set<Marker> _prepareMarkers(MapState state, MapCubit cubit, BuildContext context) {
return state.markers.map((marker) => Marker(
    markerId: marker.markerId,
    position: marker.position,
    icon: marker.icon,
    infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
      title: 'example title',
      snippet: 'example snippet',
    ),
    consumeTapEvents: true,
    onTap: () {
      state.mapController?.showMarkerInfoWindow(marker.markerId);
    },
)).toSet();
```

}